# can i delete all rows from a data extension by query?

Tags: query, dataextensions, data, sql

In sql we can delete all rows like: `DELETE FROM table_name`
how can i do the same in marketing cloud by query for a data extension? I would like to delete all rows from a data extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<sobject> g = new List<sobject>([Select id from table_name]);
delete g;
```

sobject is your object name (make a list of the object)

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding. How this will work or run? where to put this list? does not look like something that will work in query.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
SELECT * FROM [DE_Name] WHERE 1 = 2
```

Comment: How does this work?. IIUC this is _selecting_ an empty result set, it's not actually deleting anything from the data extension.